# ELI5 score function and softmax policy for policy gradient

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

H, i am following David Silver's [lecture on policy gradients](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHZVXao4qXs&t=882s) but have trouble getting some points he is making when introducing the score function.

At time [33:44](https://youtu.be/KHZVXao4qXs?t=2024) he is justifying the use of the likelihood ratio trick as follows: "By rewriting the gradient in this way we are able to take expectations. Computing expectation of this thing is hard, but computing expectation of this thing is easy because we have this policy here and it is the policy we are following".

So, my questions for this slide are the following

- what kind of expectation are we computing? Is it the **pi(s,a)**
  -- probability of taking action **a** in state **s**?
- why do we need an expectation of it at all?
- why is computing expectation of **log * pi(s,a)** easier? (maybe an example please)

And then, as we transition to the [next slide](https://youtu.be/KHZVXao4qXs?t=2202), he shows the score function for the softmax policy. I don't get how he derived it at all... is it just calculus? Could you maybe show the steps?

Thanks :)

Comment: I found the answer to the second question (re derivation of the score function for softmax) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434372/policy-gradients-log-trick-expectations-softmax-policy

Comment: [This page](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Policy_gradient_methods#Likelihood_Ratio_Methods_and_REINFORCE) explains it quite well (section about REINFORCE).

Comment: Thanks. I still didn't get 1) why we need an expectation of the gradient and 2) why computing expectation should be easier. Or did i miss something in the article?

Comment: I think this may clarify the points: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37855/policy-gradient-methods-scorefunction-logpolicy

Comment: In theory, you want to max the integral, that is you want to max your value function **forall** states and actions. You clearly cannot do that in continuous states/actions, so you approximate the integral with an expectation, and then use samples to approximate the expectation.